# R skips values of a for loop in a random way?

Tags: r

Im trying to go tru all the values of a modified column `(round((D$eff)*d,1))`, the for loop goes between all the posible values the modified column can take, but still considers that two equal values are different.
If i ran this code:

```r
suma<-function(c,d){
  D<-subset(sim)
  for (g in 0:c){
      print(g*0.1)
      D<-subset(D,  g*0.1,1!= (round((D$eff)*d,1)))
      print(round((D$eff)*d,1))
  }
  return(round((D$eff)*d,1))
}
```

it returns:

```r
[1] 2.2
  [1] 2.5 2.6 2.6 2.6 2.6 2.5 2.7 2.5 2.7 2.5 2.8 2.9 3.1 2.7 2.5 2.6 3.1 2.8
 [19] 2.8 2.3 2.4 2.4 2.5 2.3 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.3 2.5 2.4 2.4 2.5 2.4 2.4 2.5 2.4
 [37] 2.5 2.7 2.6 2.5 2.5 2.4 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.4 2.4 2.5 2.6 2.4 2.4 2.5 2.4 2.5
 [55] 2.9 2.9 3.0 3.0 2.9 2.5 2.5 2.6 2.5 2.5 2.4 2.5 2.6 2.5 2.6 2.5 2.5 2.6
 [73] 2.5 2.5 2.6 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.6 2.5 2.5 2.6 2.6 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5
 [91] 2.5 2.5 2.6 2.5 2.4 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.4 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5
[109] 2.5 2.5 2.4 2.5 2.5 2.6 2.4 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.4 2.5 2.6 2.5 2.4 2.4
[127] 2.6 2.5 2.5 2.6 2.4 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.6 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.6
[145] 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.6 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.6 2.5 2.6 2.5 2.6 2.6 2.6 2.5
[163] 2.6 2.6 2.6 2.6 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.6 2.5 2.5 2.5
[1] 2.3
  [1] 2.5 2.6 2.6 2.6 2.6 2.5 2.7 2.5 2.7 2.5 2.8 2.9 3.1 2.7 2.5 2.6 3.1 2.8
 [19] 2.8 2.3 2.4 2.4 2.5 2.3 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.3 2.5 2.4 2.4 2.5 2.4 2.4 2.5 2.4
 [37] 2.5 2.7 2.6 2.5 2.5 2.4 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.4 2.4 2.5 2.6 2.4 2.4 2.5 2.4 2.5
 [55] 2.9 2.9 3.0 3.0 2.9 2.5 2.5 2.6 2.5 2.5 2.4 2.5 2.6 2.5 2.6 2.5 2.5 2.6
 [73] 2.5 2.5 2.6 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.6 2.5 2.5 2.6 2.6 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5
 [91] 2.5 2.5 2.6 2.5 2.4 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.4 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5
[109] 2.5 2.5 2.4 2.5 2.5 2.6 2.4 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.4 2.5 2.6 2.5 2.4 2.4
[127] 2.6 2.5 2.5 2.6 2.4 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.6 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.6
[145] 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.6 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.6 2.5 2.6 2.5 2.6 2.6 2.6 2.5
[163] 2.6 2.6 2.6 2.6 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.6 2.5 2.5 2.5
[1] 2.4
  [1] 2.5 2.6 2.6 2.6 2.6 2.5 2.7 2.5 2.7 2.5 2.8 2.9 3.1 2.7 2.5 2.6 3.1 2.8
 [19] 2.8 2.3 2.4 2.4 2.5 2.3 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.3 2.5 2.4 2.4 2.5 2.4 2.4 2.5 2.4
 [37] 2.5 2.7 2.6 2.5 2.5 2.4 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.4 2.4 2.5 2.6 2.4 2.4 2.5 2.4 2.5
 [55] 2.9 2.9 3.0 3.0 2.9 2.5 2.5 2.6 2.5 2.5 2.4 2.5 2.6 2.5 2.6 2.5 2.5 2.6
 [73] 2.5 2.5 2.6 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.6 2.5 2.5 2.6 2.6 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5
 [91] 2.5 2.5 2.6 2.5 2.4 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.4 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5
[109] 2.5 2.5 2.4 2.5 2.5 2.6 2.4 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.4 2.5 2.6 2.5 2.4 2.4
[127] 2.6 2.5 2.5 2.6 2.4 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.6 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.6
[145] 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.6 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.6 2.5 2.6 2.5 2.6 2.6 2.6 2.5
[163] 2.6 2.6 2.6 2.6 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.6 2.5 2.5 2.5
[1] 2.5
 [1] 2.6 2.6 2.6 2.6 2.7 2.7 2.8 2.9 3.1 2.7 2.6 3.1 2.8 2.8 2.3 2.4 2.4 2.3 2.3
[20] 2.4 2.4 2.4 2.4 2.4 2.7 2.6 2.4 2.4 2.4 2.6 2.4 2.4 2.4 2.9 2.9 3.0 3.0 2.9
[39] 2.6 2.4 2.6 2.6 2.6 2.6 2.6 2.6 2.6 2.6 2.4 2.4 2.4 2.6 2.4 2.4 2.6 2.4 2.4
[58] 2.6 2.6 2.4 2.6 2.6 2.6 2.6 2.6 2.6 2.6 2.6 2.6 2.6 2.6 2.6 2.6
[1] 2.6
 [1] 2.7 2.7 2.8 2.9 3.1 2.7 3.1 2.8 2.8 2.3 2.4 2.4 2.3 2.3 2.4 2.4 2.4 2.4 2.4
[20] 2.7 2.4 2.4 2.4 2.4 2.4 2.4 2.9 2.9 3.0 3.0 2.9 2.4 2.4 2.4 2.4 2.4 2.4 2.4
[39] 2.4 2.4
[1] 2.7
 [1] 2.8 2.9 3.1 3.1 2.8 2.8 2.3 2.4 2.4 2.3 2.3 2.4 2.4 2.4 2.4 2.4 2.4 2.4 2.4
[20] 2.4 2.4 2.4 2.9 2.9 3.0 3.0 2.9 2.4 2.4 2.4 2.4 2.4 2.4 2.4 2.4 2.4
[1] 2.8
 [1] 2.8 2.9 3.1 3.1 2.8 2.8 2.3 2.4 2.4 2.3 2.3 2.4 2.4 2.4 2.4 2.4 2.4 2.4 2.4
[20] 2.4 2.4 2.4 2.9 2.9 3.0 3.0 2.9 2.4 2.4 2.4 2.4 2.4 2.4 2.4 2.4 2.4
[1] 2.9
 [1] 2.8 2.9 3.1 3.1 2.8 2.8 2.3 2.4 2.4 2.3 2.3 2.4 2.4 2.4 2.4 2.4 2.4 2.4 2.4
[20] 2.4 2.4 2.4 2.9 2.9 3.0 3.0 2.9 2.4 2.4 2.4 2.4 2.4 2.4 2.4 2.4 2.4
[1] 3
 [1] 2.8 2.9 3.1 3.1 2.8 2.8 2.3 2.4 2.4 2.3 2.3 2.4 2.4 2.4 2.4 2.4 2.4 2.4 2.4
[20] 2.4 2.4 2.4 2.9 2.9 2.9 2.4 2.4 2.4 2.4 2.4 2.4 2.4 2.4 2.4
[1] 3.1
 [1] 2.8 2.9 2.8 2.8 2.3 2.4 2.4 2.3 2.3 2.4 2.4 2.4 2.4 2.4 2.4 2.4 2.4 2.4 2.4
[20] 2.4 2.9 2.9 2.9 2.4 2.4 2.4 2.4 2.4 2.4 2.4 2.4 2.4
```

But is I round the left part of the inequality:

```r
suma<-function(c,d){
  D<-subset(sim)
  for (g in 0:c){
      print(g*0.1)
      D<-subset(D,  round(g*0.1,1)!= (round((D$eff)*d,1)))
      print(round((D$eff)*d,1))
  }
  return(round((D$eff)*d,1))
}
```

it returns:

```r
[1] 2.2
  [1] 2.5 2.6 2.6 2.6 2.6 2.5 2.7 2.5 2.7 2.5 2.8 2.9 3.1 2.7 2.5 2.6 3.1 2.8
 [19] 2.8 2.3 2.4 2.4 2.5 2.3 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.3 2.5 2.4 2.4 2.5 2.4 2.4 2.5 2.4
 [37] 2.5 2.7 2.6 2.5 2.5 2.4 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.4 2.4 2.5 2.6 2.4 2.4 2.5 2.4 2.5
 [55] 2.9 2.9 3.0 3.0 2.9 2.5 2.5 2.6 2.5 2.5 2.4 2.5 2.6 2.5 2.6 2.5 2.5 2.6
 [73] 2.5 2.5 2.6 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.6 2.5 2.5 2.6 2.6 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5
 [91] 2.5 2.5 2.6 2.5 2.4 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.4 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5
[109] 2.5 2.5 2.4 2.5 2.5 2.6 2.4 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.4 2.5 2.6 2.5 2.4 2.4
[127] 2.6 2.5 2.5 2.6 2.4 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.6 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.6
[145] 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.6 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.6 2.5 2.6 2.5 2.6 2.6 2.6 2.5
[163] 2.6 2.6 2.6 2.6 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.6 2.5 2.5 2.5
[1] 2.3
  [1] 2.5 2.6 2.6 2.6 2.6 2.5 2.7 2.5 2.7 2.5 2.8 2.9 3.1 2.7 2.5 2.6 3.1 2.8
 [19] 2.8 2.4 2.4 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.4 2.4 2.5 2.4 2.4 2.5 2.4 2.5 2.7 2.6
 [37] 2.5 2.5 2.4 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.4 2.4 2.5 2.6 2.4 2.4 2.5 2.4 2.5 2.9 2.9 3.0
 [55] 3.0 2.9 2.5 2.5 2.6 2.5 2.5 2.4 2.5 2.6 2.5 2.6 2.5 2.5 2.6 2.5 2.5 2.6
 [73] 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.6 2.5 2.5 2.6 2.6 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.6
 [91] 2.5 2.4 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.4 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.4
[109] 2.5 2.5 2.6 2.4 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.4 2.5 2.6 2.5 2.4 2.4 2.6 2.5 2.5
[127] 2.6 2.4 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.6 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.6 2.5 2.5 2.5
[145] 2.6 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.6 2.5 2.6 2.5 2.6 2.6 2.6 2.5 2.6 2.6 2.6
[163] 2.6 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.6 2.5 2.5 2.5
[1] 2.4
  [1] 2.5 2.6 2.6 2.6 2.6 2.5 2.7 2.5 2.7 2.5 2.8 2.9 3.1 2.7 2.5 2.6 3.1 2.8
 [19] 2.8 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.7 2.6 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.6
 [37] 2.5 2.5 2.9 2.9 3.0 3.0 2.9 2.5 2.5 2.6 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.6 2.5 2.6 2.5 2.5
 [55] 2.6 2.5 2.5 2.6 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.6 2.5 2.5 2.6 2.6 2.5 2.5 2.5
 [73] 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.6 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5
 [91] 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.6 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.6 2.5 2.6 2.5 2.5 2.6 2.5 2.5
[109] 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.6 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.6 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.6 2.5 2.5 2.5
[127] 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.6 2.5 2.6 2.5 2.6 2.6 2.6 2.5 2.6 2.6 2.6 2.6 2.5 2.5 2.5
[145] 2.5 2.6 2.5 2.5 2.5
[1] 2.5
 [1] 2.6 2.6 2.6 2.6 2.7 2.7 2.8 2.9 3.1 2.7 2.6 3.1 2.8 2.8 2.7 2.6 2.6 2.9 2.9
[20] 3.0 3.0 2.9 2.6 2.6 2.6 2.6 2.6 2.6 2.6 2.6 2.6 2.6 2.6 2.6 2.6 2.6 2.6 2.6
[39] 2.6 2.6 2.6 2.6 2.6 2.6 2.6 2.6 2.6 2.6
[1] 2.6
 [1] 2.7 2.7 2.8 2.9 3.1 2.7 3.1 2.8 2.8 2.7 2.9 2.9 3.0 3.0 2.9
[1] 2.7
 [1] 2.8 2.9 3.1 3.1 2.8 2.8 2.9 2.9 3.0 3.0 2.9
[1] 2.8
[1] 2.9 3.1 3.1 2.9 2.9 3.0 3.0 2.9
[1] 2.9
[1] 3.1 3.1 3.0 3.0
[1] 3
[1] 3.1 3.1
[1] 3.1
numeric(0)
```

Does anyone know why this happens? thank you in advance.

Comment: It's easier for us to root cause your problem if you make it repeatable. A small sample of data for `c`, `d`, and `sim` would help a lot. We don't need this big of an example. Just something to follow the data all the way through.

Comment: If your loop is running oddly then the most relevant variable would be `c`.

Comment: Maybe consider using the `near()` function in the dplyr package. Using floating point numbers with == or != comparisons is tricky.

Comment: @AdamSampson c=40, d=180 and D$eff are values close to 0.013, llike:
0.01306
0.01318
0.01302
0.01367
0.01290
0.01367
0.01367
0.01382
0.01294
0.01382
0.01338
0.01338

Comment: @Dave2e with near() I have no problem, I'll use this in the future, thank you.